# Почему переменная х не действует внутри цикла?

Tags: java, переменные, область-видимости

```
class MyDrawPanel extends JPanel {

    int x = 20;

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.fillRect(x, 20, 100, 100);
            x += 120;
        }
    }
}



   public class MyDraw {

    MyDrawPanel panel = new MyDrawPanel();
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    public void createGuiPanel() {
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, panel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyDraw draw = new MyDraw();
        draw.createGuiPanel();
    }
}
```

Comment: Как она должна "действовать"?

Comment: в качестве аргумента для метода fillRect

Comment: С чего вы взяли, что не действует? Добавьте вывод в консоль с ее значениями и вы увидите, что все "действует". Какое поведение вы ожидаете?

Comment: добавил класс, при запуске в консоли я ожидаю увидеть квадраты но их нет. Но если перенести объявление переменной x в метод PaintComponent, то все работает.

Comment: Как там может работать? PaintComponent нигде не вызывается.

Comment: Сами попробуйте. Если x объявить в классе, то квадраты не появятся, а если внутри метода то все работает. Почему?

Comment: Работает и так, и так. Но немного по-разному. Смотрите, когда `x` объявлена как инстанс-переменная класса, то при каждом вызове `paintComponent()` она будет увеличиваться на 120 и в какой-то (очень скорый) момент выйдет за пределы видимости на экране. Попробуйте сразу после запуска развернуть окно на весь экран - сработает `paintComponent()` и квадраты сместятся вправо, а при следующей прорисовке вы их уже не увидите (если у вас экран не на километр в ширину)))). Можете так и оставить, но перед циклом обновлять переменную `x = 20`

Comment: Я тоже ожидал что будет работать, но при запуске этого кода у меня квадраты вообще не отображаются.

Comment: Один раз точно должно все нарисоваться

Comment: @Эникейщик, он вызывается системой при прорисовке компонента.